# Split a percentage over 3 fields?

Tags: excel

I've got 3 cells in my spreadsheet that have the layout as below.  These values are dynamic, however what I need to do is split a percentage over the 3 fields, and then increase the number.

```
Total Staff Costs           £1,000.00
Total Hardware Costs        £0.00
Total Expenses              £400.00
```

For instance, the above comes to a total of £1400, however I need to charge 10% of my own time on top of this so £140.

What I can't just do though, is take this 10% and split it over the 3 fields, ie. I can't just add £46.70 to each field, because no hardware has been bought, so to say its £46.70 would raise some questions.  I need to split it proportionally between each one.

How can I go about adding X% to the fields proportionally?

Comment: Can't you just add 10% of each field to itself?

Comment: I could but for some reason I start getting discrepancies.  For instance, I've currently got a total of £1829.22 but the breakdown totals to £1827.52

Comment: You might be off by a couple of pennies if you take 10% of each instead of the whole, but £1.70 seems like a lot to be out unless you have over 200 line items. You could add one more "Adjustment" line and then take (`Total * 10%` - `The individual 10%s`) though but it sounds like you've got some other problem

Comment: Ah, its because its supposed to be 10% Margin, not a 10% Markup

Comment: I still feel like I'm missing something with your example above, but you could always do something with `COUNTIF` (e.g. `SUM($B:$B)*.1 / COUNTIF($B:$B,">0")`)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt the logic be to determine the percentage of the total for each field. Then multiply that percentage by the total of the 10%

so you have 3 fields totalling 1400

so 1000 / 1400 = .714286

so 0 / 1400 = 0

so 400/ 1400 = .0285714

now multiply these by the totals

so 1400 * .714286

so 1400 * 0

so 1400 * .0285714

These should total to the 10%

so all your data is in Column b in cells 1, 2, 3
The formula that would go in to the cells C1, C2, C3 (assuming you want these totals in the next column over)

```
=(B1/SUM($B:$B)) * (SUM($B:$B)*0.1) 'Cell C1
=(B2/SUM($B:$B)) * (SUM($B:$B)*0.1) 'Cell C2
=(B3/SUM($B:$B)) * (SUM($B:$B)*0.1) 'Cell C3
```

Comment: Doesn't that have the same result as `=B1*.1`? Based upon my testing: yes.

Comment: Okay... let's replace `SUM($B:$B)` with another expression just to make it easier to show what I mean. Let's use `X`. Since the passed array is fixed we know the value will always be the same within the formula. Your formula is now `(B1/X) *(X * 0.1)` or after combining both sides `(0.1 * X * B1) / X` since X is in the numerator and denominator they cancel out resulting in `0.1 * B1` or `B1*.1`. Essentially you provided a complicated method of using the same formula the OP indicated caused discrepancies.